# How do I clear the cache from @cached_property decorator?

Tags: python

I have an function called "value" that makes heavy calculation...

The result of the function is always the same if the dataset is not changed for the identifier.

Once the dataset is changed for some identifier, I want to clear the cache, and let the function calculate it again.

You can better understand me by looking at this code:

```
from functools import cached_property


class Test:
    identifiers = {}
    dataset = an empty object of dataset type

    def __init__(self, identifier, ...)
        self.identifier = identifier
        ...
        Test.identifiers[identifier] = self

    ...

    @cached_property
    def value(self):
        result = None
        # heavy calculate based on dataset
        return result

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, identifier):
        if identifier in cls.identifiers:
            return cls.identifiers[identifier]
        else:
            return cls(identifier, ...)

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, dataset):
        for block in dataset:
            # assume there is block['identifier'] in each block
            # here i want to clear the cache of value() function
            instance = cls.get(block['identifier'])
            # clear @cached_property of instance
            cls.dataset.append(block)
```

Comment: I would consider making `dataset` a read-only instance attribute rather than a mutable class attribute. If you want to change the dataset, create a new instance of `Test`.

Comment: `@lru_cache` has a `cache_clear()` function, but I don't see anything similar for `@cached_property`.

Comment: @chepner Can you give me an example please?

Comment: The documentation of `@cached_property` says that it's intended for immutable properties.

Comment: **Useful for expensive computed properties of instances that are otherwise effectively immutable.**

Comment: `t2 = Test(t1.value)`

Comment: @Barmar So should I change "cached_property" to "lru_cache"?

Comment: `lru_cache` is for caching ordinary functions, not properties.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can read in [the CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd4a3f21454a6012f4353e2255837561fc9f0e6a/Lib/functools.py#L950), the value for a `cached_property` in Python 3.8 is stored in an instance variable of the same name. This is not documented, so it may be an implementation detail that you should not rely upon.

But if you just want to get it done without regards to compatibility, you can remove the cache with `del instance.value`.

[As of Python 3.9, this is documented.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)

Comment: As of python 3.9, this behavior is documented: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property

Comment: hi, is there a way to check if the property `self.property` has being calculated before ?, I receive sometimes `del self.property ;  AttributeError:property` when the property was not calculated (or being called ) before

Comment: @Pablo: If you're clearing it so regularly that you sometimes try to clear it before you've read it the first time, maybe you just want a normal `property` instead of a cached one?

Comment: @Blckknght so the problem was that the property is very expensive to calculate, but the instance is mutable, not very much, but sometimes it mutates, anyway I found a way using the `instance.__dict__` dictionary, I added my response below :). thanks!

Comment: I agree with Pablo. It should be possible to use 'del' without being certain the cache was set, since the only documented way to check it is to access the property and _cause_ it to be set :(.  I have several cached properties and want to clear them all in a reset() method. I followed Pablo's lead with `caches = self.__dict__.keys()` and selectively deleting each property only after checking `if "property" in caches`. Kind of hacky
 `

Answer (score 3):

(Aditional to @Blckknght answer)

In case that you have a **mutable** object and you need to *refresh* all the `@cached_property` (because the object has been mutated), you could delete the properties that are already cached on the `self.__dict__` dictionary (that's where the properties are storaged)

```
from functools import cached_property

class Test:
    datalist: List[int]

    @cached_property
    def value(self):
        result = None
        # heavy calculate based on datalist
        return result

    def add_element(self, new:int)-> None:
        # restore cache if calculated 
        self.__dict__.pop('value', None) # this will delete the cached val if already cached, otherwise do nothing  
        self.datalist.append(new)
```

or in case you want to do it more elegant you can directly edit the `__setattr__` method

```
from functools import cached_property

class Test:
    datalist: List[int]

    @cached_property
    def value(self):
        result = None
        # heavy calculate based on datalist
        return result

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        self.__dict__[name] = val
        self.__dict__.pop('value', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

I offer an alternative approach, which might be useful in some cases.
If the type of the dataset you need to do the computation on is hashable, you can make use of the regular `functools.cache` or `lru_cache` decorator, applied to a static method that takes the dataset as input.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property    
    def slow_attribute(self):
        return self._slow_attribute(self.data)
        
    @staticmethod
    @lru_cache
    def _slow_attribute(data):

        # long computation, using data,
        # here is just an example

        return sum(data)
```

Here there is no need to concern yourself with when to clear the cache: if the underlying dataset changes, the staticmethod *automatically* knows it cannot use the cached value anymore.

This has the additional perk that, if the dataset were to be restored to a previously-used state, the lookup may still be able to use a cached value.

Here is a demo of the code above working:

```py
from time import perf_counter_ns

def print_time_and_value_of_computation(c):
    
    t1 = perf_counter_ns()    
    val = c.slow_attribute
    t2 = perf_counter_ns()

    print(f'Time taken: {(t2 - t1)/1000} microseconds')
    print(f'Value: {val}')


c = MyClass(range(10_000))

print_time_and_value_of_computation(c)
print_time_and_value_of_computation(c)

print('Changing the dataset!')
c.data = range(20_000)

print_time_and_value_of_computation(c)
print_time_and_value_of_computation(c)

print('Going back to the original dataset!')
c.data = range(10_000)

print_time_and_value_of_computation(c)
```

which returns:

```
Time taken: 162.074 microseconds
Value: 49995000
Time taken: 2.152 microseconds
Value: 49995000
Changing the dataset!
Time taken: 264.121 microseconds
Value: 199990000
Time taken: 1.989 microseconds
Value: 199990000
Going back to the original dataset!
Time taken: 1.144 microseconds
Value: 49995000
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem and came across this thread as I was trying to solve it.  The data in my case effectively is immutable, except that the setup of this object in some cases involves using the properties, with the properties being out of date after the setup.  @Pablo's answer was helpful, but I wanted that process to dynamically reset everything cached.

Here's a generic example:

Setup and broken thing:

```
from functools import cached_property


class BaseThing:
    def __init__(self, *starting_numbers: int):
        self.numbers = []
        self.numbers.extend(starting_numbers)

    @property
    def numbers_as_strings(self) -> dict[int, str]:
        """This property method will be referenced repeatedly"""

    def process_arbitrary_numbers(self, *arbitrary_numbers: int) -> list[str]:
        return [self.numbers_as_strings.get(number) for number in arbitrary_numbers]

    def extend_numbers(self, *additional_numbers: int):
        self.numbers.extend(additional_numbers)


class BrokenThing(BaseThing):
    @cached_property
    def numbers_as_strings(self) -> dict[int, str]:
        print("Working on:", " ".join(map(str, self.numbers)))
        return {number: str(number) for number in self.numbers}
```

output:

```
>>> thing = BrokenThing(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> thing.process_arbitrary_numbers(1, 3) == ["1", "3"]
Working on: 1 2 3 4
True
>>> thing.extend_numbers(4, 5, 6)
>>> thing.process_arbitrary_numbers(5, 6) == ["5", "6"]
False
```

`@cached_property` replaced with `@property` to make it work, leaving it inefficient:

```
class InefficientThing(BaseThing):
    @property
    def numbers_as_strings(self) -> dict[int, str]:
        print("Working on:", " ".join(map(str, self.numbers)))
        return {number: str(number) for number in self.numbers}
```

output:

```
>>> thing = InefficientThing(1, 2, 3)
>>> thing.process_arbitrary_numbers(1, 3) == ["1", "3"]
Working on: 1 2 3
Working on: 1 2 3
True
>>> thing.extend_numbers(4, 5, 6)
>>> thing.process_arbitrary_numbers(5, 6) == ["5", "6"]
Working on: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Working on: 1 2 3 4 5 6
True
```

Solution:

```
class EfficientThing(BaseThing):
    def _clear_cached_properties(self):
        for name in dir(type(self)):
            if isinstance(getattr(type(self), name), cached_property):
                print(f"Clearing self.{name}")
                vars(self).pop(name, None)

    def extend_numbers(self, *additional_numbers: int):
        self._clear_cached_properties()
        return super().extend_numbers(*additional_numbers)

    @cached_property
    def numbers_as_strings(self) -> dict[int, str]:
        print("Working on:", " ".join(map(str, self.numbers)))
        return {number: str(number) for number in self.numbers}
```

output:

```
>>> thing = EfficientThing(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> thing.process_arbitrary_numbers(1, 3) == ["1", "3"]
Working on: 1 2 3 4
True
>>> thing.extend_numbers(4, 5, 6)
Clearing self.numbers_as_strings
>>> thing.process_arbitrary_numbers(5, 6) == ["5", "6"]
Working on: 1 2 3 4 4 5 6
True
```

This loops through all attributes of the object's parent class.  If the value of the attribute is an instance of `cached_property`, it's most likely a cached_property.  The attribute is then popped from the instance dictionary.  `None` is passed to `pop` in case the property hadn't been cached yet.